# OpenThread - Node always detached - CC2650

Tags: c, texas-instruments, openthread

I'm trying to use OpenThread in a CC2650 Launchpad, following their example commands at [this link](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/cc2650).

However, the state of the node stays detached forever. And if I try to manually set the state to leader, the node outputs error 29, which according to the [reference page about status codes in OpenThread](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/doc/spinel-protocol-src/spinel-status-codes.md), it corresponds to a reserved code.

How can I can turn on the leader mode in this case?

Comment: That error code indicates kThreadError_NotCapable - https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/include/openthread/types.h#L185. This means that device doesn't support being a leader.

Comment: Are you connecting to an existing network, or trying to create one? By default, I believe that device only supports the 'child' role, and can't create a network itself.

Comment: take a look at this stick, maybe u can play around with that one: https://www.tindie.com/products/slaesh/cc2652-zigbee-coordinator-or-openthread-router/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Nick on the comments of the question, error 29 means that the device doesn't support being a leader. Taking a look at the description of the [CC2650 OpenThread repo](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/cc2650), we can see that this chip doesn't have memory to have all capabilities of OpenThread, so the developers should have excluded the leader mode.